# Open GL - How to load texture from pixel buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I want to draw on a quad a texture. I want to bind my texture from a 1D unsigned char buffer of pixels organized as follow :

[image]

Each pixel is composed of 2 bytes, these 2 bytes are a 16bits grayscale value.

I actually tried a lot of things but I can't see anything on my quad :

```
void RawImageDrawer::initializeGL() {
  glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
  glClearDepth(1.0f); 
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glDepthFunc((GL_LEQUAL));
  glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}

void RawImageDrawer::resizeGL(int width, int height) {
  if (height == 0)
    height = 1;
  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);*/
  glLoadIdentity();
}

void RawImageDrawer::loadTexture() {
  glGenTextures(1, &texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
    0, 
    GL_RED, 
    1024, 
    1024, 
    0, 
    GL_LUMINANCE, 
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
    buffer //unsigned char* described up there
  );
}

void RawImageDrawer::paintGL() {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity(); 
  glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0,0); glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(0,1); glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(1,1); glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(1,0); glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
  glEnd();
}
```

I also tried to change TEXTURE_2D to TEXTURE_1D, didn't change anything..

Answer (score 1):

Since your buffer is 16-bit grayscale, you shall specify `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` instead of `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. Make sure that your values spread the whole [0, 65535] range, because for 16-bit data 65535 is the full luminosity value.

Also `GL_RED` was never a valid value for `internalFormat` parameter of `glTexImage2D`. You should rather use `GL_R16` for the `internalFormat` and `GL_RED` for the `format` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, made these changes but I still got the problem.. Using TEXTURE_2D make my program crash at the glTexImage2D function call. Using TEXTURE_1D doesn't crash my program but does nothing on the quad. Do my uchar* array needs to have padding before and after the actual data ?

Comment: @LaurentJerber: By default the offset between the rows has to be a multiple of four bytes, but it's already the case in the code you posted. If it still crashes, the problem must be elsewhere in the code you didn't post. Particularly look how you allocate the buffer, perhaps you have a bug there.